# php foreach how to filter image names to display certain images you want

Tags: php

Files are

> AAA_1.jpg AAA_2.jpg AAA_3.jpg BBB_1.jpg BBB_2.jpg CCC_1.jpg

```
foreach ($carousel as $image) {
    echo "<img src='images/$image'>";
}
```

How to filter image names, just to display AAA_ images.
result to see

```
<img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
<img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
<img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
```

Comment: Is it really so hard to put a basic `if()` test in there to check for `AAA` in the filename strings?

Comment: Depends how you're generating your $carousel array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a probalby a million ways to do this, but I would just check the name of the image to see it begins with 'AAA_'

```
foreach ($carousel as $image) {
    if(strpos($image,'AAA_') === 0){
      echo "<img src='images/carousel/$image'>";
   }
}
```

Or more complex, but still fun, entertainingly worth the extra performance hit of explode:

```
foreach ($carousel as $image) {
   $image_parts = explode('_', $image);
   if($image_parts[0] == 'AAA'){
      echo "<img src='images/carousel/$image'>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Should be `strpos` and not `$strpos` tho

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($carousel as $image) {
    if(substr($image, 0, 3) == 'AAA'( {
        echo "<img src='images/carousel/$image'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know all your file, you can use that code, also use in_array ;-)

```
$carousel = array('AAA_1.jpg', 'AAA_2.jpg', 'AAA_3.jpg','BBB_1.jpg','BBB_2.jpg','CCC_1.jpg');
$entry = array('AAA_1.jpg', 'AAA_2.jpg', 'AAA_3.jpg');

foreach ($carousel as $image) {
    if(in_array($image, $entry)) {
        echo "<img src='images/carousel/$image'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using substr and strlen you will be able to get the images you want starting with the prefix variables value.

```
$prefix = 'AAA_';

$carousel = array(
   "AAA_1.jpg",
   "AAA_2.jpg",
   "AAA_3.jpg",
   "BBB_1.jpg",
   "BBB_2.jpg",
   "CCC_1.jpg"
);

foreach ($carousel as $k => $v) {
   if (substr($v, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
      echo "<img src=\"images/{$v}\" alt=\"image {$k}\" />";   
   }
}
```